# Django: populate a choice field based on a value selected in a previous form field

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I am wondering how to populate a choice field (contact and additional contacts) based on a value selected in a previous form field (company). For example my form:

```
class AddTicketForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = (
            'issue_type',
            'company',
            'contact',
            'additional_contacts',
            'priority',
            'subject',
            'description',
        )
```

From the model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):

    issue_type = models.ForeignKey(SubIssueType)

    contact = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='ticket_contact',
    )

    assigned_to = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='ticket_assigned_to',
    )

    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
    )

    additional_contacts = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

    priority = models.CharField(
        'Priority',
        max_length=50,
        choices = ticket_priority_choices,
    )

    subject = models.CharField(
        'Subject',
        max_length=255,
    )

    description = models.TextField(
        'Description',
    )

    ...

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
    )

    phone_number = models.CharField(
        'Phone Number',
        max_length=12,
    )

    relationship = models.CharField(
        'Relationship',
        max_length=30,
        choices=(
            ('customer', 'Customer'),
            ('support', 'Support'),
        )
    )
    ...
```

So, based on what's chosen for company, I would like to only populate the contact and additonal contacts with users who are members of that company. Is this possible to do with Django purely or do I need to consider JavaScript to help here? Would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: You will need a basic understanding of javascript and perhaps [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) to accomplish this.

Comment: Does it have to be a one page form?

Comment: Instead of trying to do that in server side, do it in client side. Instead of using form tag in template, just generate form HTML dynamically. Just the name of the field should be same.

Comment: @Bibhas Thank you for the pointers. I must admit that your comment would have made a wonderful answer, if accompanied with a minimal example for illustration : )